# What meaning is return a(function () )?

Tags: javascript

I studied simple asynchronized JavaScript code, but stuck with return value(function() ). I don't understand it.

How does operate this return value(function())?

```
function _async(func) {
    return function () {
        arguments[arguments.length++] = function (result) {
            _callback(result);
        };

        (function wait(args){
            for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                if (args[i] && args[i].name == '_async_cb_receiver')
                    return args[i](function (arg) {
                        args[i] = arg; wait(args);
                    })}
            func.apply(null, args);

        })(arguments);

        var _callback;

        function _async_cb_receiver(callback) {
            _callback = callback;
        }

        return _async_cb_receiver;
    };
}
```

---

```
return args[i](function (arg) {
    args[i] = arg; wait(args);
})
```

I don't understand this part.
`wait(args)` just returns `args[i]`, but parentheses appear and anonymous function is executed. How does this function handle `args[i]` and what arguments are in `arg`?

Answer (score 0):

`args` is an array of functions. So `args[i]` is one of these functions, and `args[i](something)` calls that function with `something` as the argument.

In this case, `something` is another function. This function replaces `args[i]` with its own argument, then calls `wait(args)` recursively.

This code is pretty convoluted, so I'm not sure what it's doing as a whole. I suspect it's doing something similar to the way promises work, but was written before they were added to the language.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't think args[i] is function. Thank you. In other words, args[i] is function that has anonymous function-function(arg) {} -as argument and is return value of wait()
 function, isn't it?

Comment: Any time you put `()` after something, it must be a function, since `()` is the operator for calling functions. It doesn't have any return value, since it doesn't have a `return` statement. It just calls `wait(args)` and ignores the return value.